# jQuery .hover effect 'color' not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to get a simple jQuery color hover effect for a tags.  You can in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7THhg/7/) that it's not working properly.  Also, how would I get an easing effect on it?  Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var origColor = $("#links-top-contact").children('a').css("color");
    $("links-top-contact").children('a').hover(function() {
        $(this).css('color' , 'blue');   
            $("links-top-contact").children('a').hover(function() {   
                $(this).css(origColor); 
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var origColor = $("#links-top-contact a").css("color");
    $("#links-top-contact a").hover(function() {
        $(this).css({color:'blue'});
    },function() {
        $(this).css({color:origColor});
    });
});
```

Updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/uHYVf/

Comment: Awesome thank you!  Just curious, what is the extra bracket and comma for: $(this).css({color:'blue'});
         --------------------> }, <------HERE.  I keep seeing that syntax and it just seem out of place.

Comment: The hover event in jQuery can take 2 functions. the first is mouse over, the second is mouse out. See here for more info http://api.jquery.com/hover/